# numpy/pandas effective multiplication of arrays/dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two pandas data frames, which look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_one = pd.DataFrame( {
    'A': [1,1,2,3,4,4,4],
    'B1': [0.5,0.0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1],
    'B2': [0.2,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.2],
    'B3': [0.1,0.2,0.0,0.9,0.0,0.3,0.5]} );
df_two = pd.DataFrame( {
    'A': [1,2,3,4],
    'C1': [1.0,9.0,2.1,9.0],
    'C2': [2.0,3.0,0.7,1.1],
    'C3': [5.0,4.0,2.3,3.4]} );

df_one
   A   B1   B2   B3
0  1  0.5  0.2  0.1
1  1  0.0  0.3  0.2
2  2  0.2  0.1  0.0
3  3  0.1  0.5  0.9
4  4  0.3  0.3  0.0
5  4  0.2  0.1  0.3
6  4  0.1  0.2  0.5

df_two
   A   C1   C2   C3
0  1  1.0  2.0  5.0
1  2  9.0  3.0  4.0
2  3  2.1  0.7  2.3
3  4  9.0  1.1  3.4
```

What I would like to do is compute is a scalar product where I would be multiplying rows of the first data frame by the rows of the second data frame, i.e., `\sum_i B_i * C_i`, but in such a way that a row in the first data frame is multiplied by a row in the second data frame only if the values of the `A` column match in both frames. I know how to do it looping and using if's but I would like to do that in a more efficient numpy-like or pandas-like way. Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: how about something with pandas `groupby`? is that any good hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want unique values for column A (If you do, use groupby on the result below)

```
pd.merge(df_one, df_two, on='A')
   A   B1   B2   B3   C1   C2   C3
0  1  0.5  0.2  0.1  1.0  2.0  5.0
1  1  0.0  0.3  0.2  1.0  2.0  5.0
2  2  0.2  0.1  0.0  9.0  3.0  4.0
3  3  0.1  0.5  0.9  2.1  0.7  2.3
4  4  0.3  0.3  0.0  9.0  1.1  3.4
5  4  0.2  0.1  0.3  9.0  1.1  3.4
6  4  0.1  0.2  0.5  9.0  1.1  3.4

    pd.merge(df_one, df_two, on='A').apply(lambda s: sum([s['B%d'%i] * s['C%d'%i] for i in range(1, 4)]) , axis=1)
0    1.40
1    1.60
2    2.10
3    2.63
4    3.03
5    2.93
6    2.82
```

Comment: Thank you so much @user1827356 ! I spent more than an hour implementing what you did with merge... Had no idea about it. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be something similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_one = pd.DataFrame( {
    'A': [1,1,2,3,4,4,4],
    'B1': [0.5,0.0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1],
    'B2': [0.2,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1,0.2],
    'B3': [0.1,0.2,0.0,0.9,0.0,0.3,0.5]} );
df_two = pd.DataFrame( {
    'A': [1,2,3,4],
    'C1': [1.0,9.0,2.1,9.0],
    'C2': [2.0,3.0,0.7,1.1],
    'C3': [5.0,4.0,2.3,3.4]} );
lookup = df_two.groupby(df_two.A)

def multiply_rows(row):
    other = lookup.get_group(row['A'])
    # We want every column after "A"
    x = row.values[1:]
    # In this case, other is a 2D array with one row, similar to "row" above...
    y = other.values[0, 1:]
    return x.dot(y)

# The "axis=1" makes each row to be passed in, rather than each column
result = df_one.apply(multiply_rows, axis=1)
print result
```

This results in:

```
0    1.40
1    1.60
2    2.10
3    2.63
4    3.03
5    2.93
6    2.82
```

Answer (score 0):

I would zip together the rows and use a filter or a comprehension that takes only the rows where A columns match.

Something like

```
[scalar_product(a,b) for a,b in zip (frame1, frame2) if a[0]==b[0]]
```

assuming that you're willing to fill in the appropriate material for scalar_product

(apologies if I've made a thinko here - this code is for example purposes only and has not been tested!)